# Calculating the gini impurity of a vector in R

Tags: r, classification

I'm working on a problem in R and trying to compute the Gini index as part of a binary classification problem, initially for a vector where all values are different. I'm a bit puzzled as I would expect to get a result of 1 for perfect ienquality, however using Gini functions I'm getting different results, for example with `Gini()` function from the `DescTools` library:

```
samplevector <- c(0:20)
Gini(samplevector)
[1] 0.3666667
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing what the Gini index compute. In your example, you are giving a vector of incomes that are not totally unequal in the sense of the Gini index. If you want an index of 1:

```
samplevector <- c(rep(0,100),100)
Gini(samplevector)

[1] 1
```

Here `samplevector` is a totally inequal distribution of income: someone possess everything, all the others have nothing. The opposite :

```
samplevector <- c(rep(100,100))
Gini(samplevector)

[1] 8.760354e-18
```

Here everybody has the same income, and you get a Gini index of almost 0. In your example, you have an intermediate situation.

Comment: I was actually looking for the Gini impurity, as a decision tree splitting metric, as in here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/gini-coefficient-vs-gini-impurity-decision-trees